# i use gulp-postcss and postcss-cssnext to translate css，and got problems

Tags: css, gulp, postcss, cssnext

i use cssnext to write my css

```
:root{
    --ellipsis: {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    };
};
```

and use @apply --ellipsis in 3 places

```
.div1{
    @apply --ellipsis
}
.div2{
    @apply --ellipsis
}
.div3{
    @apply --ellipsis
}
```

and i use gulp and postcss-cssnext

```
gulp.task('postcss',function(){
    return gulp.src('src/css/*.css')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(postcss([
            cssnext({
                browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'Android >= 4.0'],
                features: {
                    rem: false
                }
            })
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});
```

but only the first place is useful，

```
.div1{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
.div2{
}
.div3{
}
```

i have to write like this:

```
:root{
    --ellipsis: {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    };
};
.div1{
    @apply --ellipsis
}
:root{
    --ellipsis: {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    };
};
.div2{
    @apply --ellipsis
}
:root{
    --ellipsis: {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    };
};
.div3{
    @apply --ellipsis
}
```

but this must not be written like that,there must be something wrong...

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^7.0.0",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^2.11.0",
}
```

who can save me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh...I fixed it myself....

I feel that is not my fault but the problem of gulp-postcss,it is the newest version,so I install an old one 6.4.0,and it worked...

Comment: If you want to accept your own answer this will help future vistors. thx